# String isomorphism definition: Is it for any arbitrary group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, graph-isomorphism

[Scott Aaronson's blog](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2521), I find the description of string isomorphism as-

> you’re given two strings $x$ and $y$ over some finite alphabet, as well as
>   the generators of a group $G$ of permutations of the string indices. 
>   The problem is to determine whether you can transform $x$ to $y$ by
>   applying a permutation in $G$.  Or even more generally: given a string
>   $x$, find a full set of generators for the subgroup of $G$ that fixes $x$.

Is $G$ an arbitrary permutation group i.e. in  the definition of string isomorphism, can we condiser any permutation group $G$ ?

I have read another [blog](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/permutation-problems-with-strings/).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure looks like $G$ can be any subgroup of $S_n$, where $n$ is the (common) length of $x$ and $y$. At least in the part you're quoting there's nothing that would restrict it to only some of these groups.

Comment: Thanks.My motivation is this -  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36132/implication-of-empty-set-as-output-of-string-isomorphism .